# Is NP-hardness closed?

Tags: reductions, np-hard

Let $X\leq Y$.

- **If $X$ is $NP$-hard, is $Y$ $NP$-hard?** I think yes, as if an $NP$ problem is reducible to $X$ in polynomial time, then surely it is also reducible to $Y$ given that $X\leq Y$.
- **If $Y$ is $NP$-hard, is $X$ $NP$-hard?** Not sure how to tackle this. Are some $P$ problems reducible to an $NP$-hard problem? If yes, then I think the answer is no but that's just intuition.

I'm trying to find a problem that is reducible to an $NP$-hard problem but itself is not $NP$-hard. However, I don't know how to identify that a problem is **not** $NP$-hard.

Comment: Your first observation is correct. In fact, this is the main point of polynomial-time reductions. For the second point, what have you tried?

Comment: Hint: all problems in NP reduce to any NP-hard problem.

Comment: P problems can always be reduced to NP problems: we can always make an algorithm worse.